# TOP 3 records for each Item in stock

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a stored procedure that goes through selected stock items, row by row, and populates a table with the 3 most recent sales order numbers for each of those stock items:

```
INSERT  INTO TOP3_STOCK_SALES_DATA
        ( ORDERDATE ,
          SEQNO ,
          STOCKCODE ,
          QUANTITY ,
          ROW
        )
        SELECT TOP 3
                h.ORDERDATE ,
                h.SEQNO ,
                l.STOCKCODE ,
                l.ORD_QUANT ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY h.ORDERDATE DESC, h.SEQNO DESC ) AS row
        FROM    SALESORD_HDR h ,
                SALESORD_LINES l
        WHERE   l.HDR_SEQNO = h.SEQNO
                AND l.STOCKCODE IN ( '1000-ACQ45' )
        ORDER BY h.ORDERDATE DESC ,
                h.SEQNO DESC
```

Is there a way to run this statement (or to get the same results) in bulk, rather than row by row?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and what the results should be?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by “in bulk”, by “row by row”, and why you want to convert the latter into the former.

Comment: The insert statement is being done for one stock code at a time. Say if I have 25 stock codes to process, I want to be able to do it in one insert statement for all 25 stock codes. It would get the most recent 3 sales orders for each stock code, i.e. 75 rows to be inserted at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your written query will not return TOP 3 for each stock item but it will return only the TOP 3 records from the returned result set. To get the TOP 3 for each stock Item see below.

```
INSERT  INTO TOP3_STOCK_SALES_DATA
        ( ORDERDATE ,
          SEQNO ,
          STOCKCODE ,
          QUANTITY ,
          ROW
        )
SELECT   A.ORDERDATE 
        ,A.SEQNO 
        ,A.STOCKCODE 
        ,A.ORD_QUANT
        ,A.row 
FROM (
        SELECT 
                h.ORDERDATE ,
                h.SEQNO ,
                l.STOCKCODE ,
                l.ORD_QUANT ,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY l.STOCKCODE ORDER BY h.ORDERDATE DESC, h.SEQNO DESC ) AS row
        FROM    SALESORD_HDR h 
        INNER JOIN  SALESORD_LINES l   ON   l.HDR_SEQNO = h.SEQNO
       ) A
WHERE ROW <= 3
```

Comment: I haven't tested it out fully yet, but that looks like it answers my question perfectly - thank you! I had no idea how to do it in a "bulk' way.

Comment: Out of interest, can I ask why you coded the join the way you did? (Inner join SALESORD_LINES l ON l.HDR_SEQNO = h.SEQNO). Is it personal preference, or is there a performance advantage?

Comment: they way you joined both tables is a valid syntax but it is only syntax for join, I have changed it to the newer syntax for join using ON clause and using key word INNER JOIN. this is the preferred syntax :)

Comment: Thanks :) I've not used SQL for a few years, so interested to see what has changed in the meantime